# Multiple container, different services, exposing securely

Tags: networking, debian, raspberry-pi, docker

I have an old computer that I have converted into a personal server running debian with multiple services running on docker and others running on the host. Also, I have a raspberry pi next to it, running other services like pi-hole and Homebridge. I need to access some of these services outside my local network. For now, insecurely it's easy to do but I would like to make things a bit more secure, I have a domain name (which I will not expose here for obvious reasons haha) and I would like to use it to redirect to my different services using subdomains. I already saw answers using nginx but while I am not using it I don't know if it can be applied to my weird installation. So, my question is the following, what would be the best way to achieve this ? Is it even possible or do I need to change something ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set up a reverse proxy with https.  Among other options are Apache and NGINX.  The idea here is the reverse proxy has an https cert assigned to it and it in turn gets the http pages and forwards them on over https.

Another solution - if the pages are not for wider consumption is to set up a VPN server on your router (there are other ways but they are harder), and then access the data across the VPN.  You would also need to block direct access to the applications rxcept through the VPN. This is harder to set up but considerably more secure if done properly because the remote user requires VPN credentials, so there is an element of mutual authentication before the service is even available.